# Changing the local directory of a Github repository

Tags: git, github

I have been pushing updates to a personal project from my company network U:Drive to Github (when I'm in the office, I can't change directory to my C:Drive from the command prompt - an IT permissions thing - so I had to set it up on U:).

I'm now at a point where I'll be doing all of my work on it at home or in the library opposite work (where, without automatic access to the U:Drive, my CMD defaults to the C:Drive) and connecting back to the U:Drive over VPN is slow, annoying, drops out, isn't always available, etc.

What I've been trying to do is set Github up to recognise C:\Users{me}\Documents\JavaProjects\agileJava as the place I'll be pushing from instead of U:\JavaProjects\agileJava but I'm hitting issues. I've cloned the repository to the C:Drive and set up an agileJava2 branch but, when I come to merge changes back to Master, it doesn't like it because the two don't have common commit histories.

Really, given I'll no longer be working on the project from U:\JavaProjects\agileJava, I'd just like to switch the Master over and not have to branch it at all. Sounds simple in principle but I can't work out how to do it from what I've researched online, if anyone could enlighten me?

Comment: I don't think this is anything to do with directories, you can generally put the clone wherever you want. It's hard to tell what exactly is wrong from so little information, though.

Comment: *it doesn't like it because the two don't have common commit histories* -- did you somehow re-initialize the git (using `git init`)? if so.. thats the problem, moving git directory is pretty simple as long as you keep the hidden `.git` folder along with the files (rather, you can just move the `.git` and do reset later, though your uncommitted changes will be lost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Bagus Tesa: moving the git directory is pretty simple as long as you keep the hidden .git folder along with the files. Doing this solved my problem.